# VBS website login script - "Object required" error

Tags: authentication, vbscript

I'm trying to write my first website login script but always getting an error in line 9 position 9 saying:

> "Object Required: 'getElementByID(...)' 800A01A8.

Here's my code for the real working site:

```
Call Main

Function Main
Set IE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application", "IE_")
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate "https://www.valuedopinions.com/eng/signin"
Wait IE
With IE.Document
    .getElementByID("tx_voputilities_pi1[email]").value = "my@email.com"
    .getElementByID("tx_voputilities_pi1[password]").value = "mypassword"
    .getElementByID("tx_voputilities_pi1[sign_in]")(0).Submit
End With
End Function

Sub Wait(IE)
Do
WScript.Sleep 500
Loop While IE.ReadyState < 4 And IE.Busy
End Sub
```

How can I write working code?

Comment: As a side-note: `IE.ReadyState < 4 And IE.Busy` is redundant. Either of the two conditions will suffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your login form elements have the `name` rather than `id`, so you need to use [`getElementsByName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByName). Also, `INPUT` elements don't have the `Submit` method, use `click` instead:

```
With IE.Document
    .getElementsByName("tx_voputilities_pi1[email]")(0).value = "my@email.com"
    .getElementsByName("tx_voputilities_pi1[password]")(0).value = "mypassword"
    .getElementsByName("tx_voputilities_pi1[sign_in]")(0).click
End With
```